# How to fix a looping bug with Scanner.nextDouble()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have run into a looping bug with my code, I am using Scanner to grab input from the user with the first two using `.nextLine()` with a semi-colon delimiter and the issue lies with `.nextDouble()`.

```java
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UseAccount {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Scanner declaration
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Change the delimiter
    keyboard.useDelimiter(";");
    Account myAccount;
    Account yourAccount;

    myAccount = new Account();
    yourAccount = new Account();

    out.println("Account 1 name: ");
    myAccount.name = keyboard.nextLine();
    out.println("Account 1 address: ");
    myAccount.address = keyboard.nextLine();
    // Issue is here
    out.println("Account 1 balance: ");
    myAccount.balance = keyboard.nextDouble();

    out.println("Account 2 name: ");
    myAccount.name = keyboard.nextLine();
    out.println("Account 2 address: ");
    myAccount.address = keyboard.nextLine();
    out.println("Account 2 balance: ");
    myAccount.balance = keyboard.nextDouble();

    out.print(myAccount.name);
    out.print(" (" + myAccount.address + ") ");
    out.print("has $" + myAccount.balance);
    out.println();

    out.print(yourAccount.name);
    out.print(" (" + yourAccount.address + ") ");
    out.print("has $" + yourAccount.balance);
    out.println();

    keyboard.close();
  }
}
```

The account class declared early on is:

```java
public class Account {
    String name;
    String address;
    double balance;
```

Output currently looks like this:

```
Account 1 name:
John Doe
Account 1 Address:
1234 Main St
Account 1 Balance:
30.22.
<Blank>
<Blank>
```

Expected Output after Account 1 Balance should lead to the same set but for Account 2 instead.

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: Can you provide the input?

Comment: The input I used was John Doe, 1234 Main St, 30.22

Comment: Why do you use `";"` as a delimiter?  How is that used?

Comment: I used it as space is the default delimiter so I altered it so the code would recognize spaces as part of the string for the address

Comment: But you're using `nextLine` to capture the address anyway, so that isn't affected by the delimiter.

Comment: @DavidBush But you aren't even using tokens at all, so what difference does it make?  `readLine()` reads the line regardless of the delimiter.  I think the problem though is that while it reads the line, it's _not_ advancing the token.  So the next token _isn't_ a double and thus it throws an input mismatch exception...which you aren't seeing because it's waiting for the next delimiter (which you never type).

Comment: @DavidBush Add a `keyboard.nextLine();` after nextDouble() and for Account2 you have to use `yourAccount` and not `myAccount`

Comment: I was using nextLine to start with but it was still causing issues for me which is why I changed the delimeter, how do I advance the token, I am fairly new to java.

Comment: thanks for the typo grab, totally missed that, thanks for the help

Comment: @DavidBush I suggest using [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) in this case instead of `Scanner`.  You can read each line of input, the balance can then by simply converted to a `double` via [`Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-)...or you can stick with `Scanner` but just use the `Scanner.readLine()` method (but I don't think it makes sense to use a `Scanner` unless you are going to tokenize the input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your delimiter pattern. Check by removing it, it should work then.
I tried by removing delimiter and it is working fine. do not worry about space character as you are already accepting input using nextLine().

Comment: No, it still doesn't work because the `nextDouble()` will leave current position on _that_ line, thus the second account will always automatically be read as having a blank name (because it's reading the rest of the balance's line--which is empty).

Comment: Thanks removing the delimiter fixed it along with @Jens suggestion to add the     keyboard.nextLine()

Comment: @DavidBush IMO, adding the `keyboard.nextLine()` after `keyboard.nextDouble()` is a hack and isn't a good practice.  The fact that the way you coded requires this hack suggests you aren't reading input properly...but that's just my two cents.

Comment: I most likely am not reading the input properly but I am just learning java and programming, really just started in the last couple days, this was an example of a book that I tried to modify to try something different and apply other things I have picked up.